# Program is not printing completely

Tags: c, if-statement, io, conditional-statements

I am comparatively new to programming, i am having some error here which i can not understand at all.Can some one help me out please.
Thank you!

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int roll,phy,che,ca,total;
    float percentage;
    char name[20];
    
    printf("enter the name of student: ");  //studentname
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("enter the roll number: ");      //roll number
    scanf("%d",&roll);
    printf("enter the marks obtained in phy,che,ca: "); //marks obtained/subject
    scanf("%d%d%d ",&phy,&che,&ca);
    
    //doesnt works from here.
    
    total= (phy+che+ca);        //calculating total marks 
    printf("the total marks obtained is %d\n",total); 
    percentage =total/3.0;          //calculating percentage student got.
    printf("the total percentage obtained is %d\n",percentage);
    
    if(percentage>=80)
        printf("first division\n");             //first division
    else if(percentage>=60 && percentage<=80)
        printf("second division\n");            //second division
    else if(percentage>=60)
        printf("third divison\n");              //third division
    else if(percentage>=10)
        printf("you failed!\n");                //failed
    else
        printf("invalid input\n");              //invalid input
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

[screenshot of the compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BINq.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add pictures of text. Instead just copy&paste the text directly into your question.

Comment: One problem is you're trying to use `%d` format for a `float`.  That won't work.

Comment: `name` is already a pointer, no `'&'` before it in `scanf("%s",&name);` You can't use ANY input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** to validate whether the input succeeded or failed. Unless you provide a *width-modifier* in your `"%s"` conversion, it is no safer than using `gets()`. See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102)

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Please [read guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions. The [scanf](https://www.mankier.com/3/scanf) function could get handful, so I strongly recommend reading the linked manual page first. If you are trying this on non-standard compilers like TurboC or older Microsoft Visual C++, please read their documentation thoroughly. And when you find it difficult, please ask a clear and specific question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d%d%d ",&phy,&che,&ca);
```

There is an extra blank character in format. So you should input a more character after you input 3 integers.

And you shouldn't use `%d` to print a float type variable, you should use `%f`.